# Mule ESB JDBC inbound endpoint: 'abstract-transformer'

Tags: jdbc, mule

I'm trying to add a transformer to a jdbc inbound endpoint, but I'm getting following error message:

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.2: The value of {abstract} in the element declaration for 'abstract-transformer' must be false.      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)`

here is the config:

```
       <jdbc:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" 
                           queryKey="orderSelect" 
                           responseTimeout="10000" 
                           mimeType="text/plain" 
                           queryTimeout="-1" 
                           pollingFrequency="${oms.new.data.polling.interval}" 
                           connector-ref="jdbcConnector" 
                           transformer-refs="ResourceLocker" 
                           doc:name="Select New Orders" >
                           <abstract-transformer class="com.pb.oms.mule.transformer.ResourceUnlocker" 
                                                 name="ResourceUnlocker"
                                                 abstract="false"
                                                 doc:name="ResourceUnlocker" />
    </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: What is this in? A container?

Comment: I forgot to say it's Mule ESB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a global custom-transformer like the following:

```
<custom-transformer class="com.pb.oms.mule.transformer.ResourceUnlocker" 
                                             name="ResourceUnlocker"
                                             abstract="false"
                                             doc:name="ResourceUnlocker" />
```

and the include it within your inbound endpoint using the a

```
<transformer ref="ResourceUnlocker" />
```

You can find the documentation on the topic [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Endpoints)